# K-Means Clustering Analysis in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, probability, k-means

I'm trying to graphically visualize a single cluster based on a relatively sparse dataframe/matrix (below). I'm not sure why I keep getting the following error:

```
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance`
```

Here is the code snippet that I have used in this analysis.

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(gridExtra)

kmeans2 = kmeans(df, centers=1, nstart=5) # df (see table below) contains probabilities

fviz_cluster(kmeans2, data=df, scale=F) # Visualize the cluster
```

This is the dataframe ("df") used in the code above. As you may have noticed, most values as close to 0. Is there any adjustment/transformation that I could make to be able to successfully perform a cluster analysis ?

```
           a          b          c          d         e          f          g          h          i           j
 0.06906453 0.01083181 0.01627455 0.03762042 0.1144168 0.01529368 0.03265494 0.08005074 0.08902436 0.003516431
           k         l         m          n         o          p            q          r          s         t
 0.01686642 0.0410222 0.0133853 0.07202466 0.0890314 0.01146801 0.0002297176 0.04715371 0.07463133 0.1023295
           u           v          w            x          y            z
 0.02023235 0.005822369 0.02169929 0.0003092351 0.01494907 9.718769e-05
```

Comment: The error is because there is a column that is just one number, ie it has 0 variance. Drop the column and try again

Comment: Just for being sure and clear, the dataframe has a-z columns and 1 row? or there are multiple more rows?

Comment: Yes, it has a-z columns and just one row.

Comment: You will have to transpose, `df` with `t(df)` so that you have a-z rows and one column. Kmeans assumes that rows are observations and columns are variables/attributes of an observation. You cannot cluster one row.